# Ayuda con validacion de correo Ajax + php

Tags: php, ajax

tengo el siguiente codigo;

```
function checkemail()
{
 var email=document.getElementById( "emailReg" ).value;

 if(email)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'check_email.php',
  data: {
   user_email:email,
  },
  success: function (response) {
   $( '#confirmUsername' ).html(response);
   if(response=="OK")   
   {
    $('#ResetSubmit').attr('disabled','');
    return true;    
   }
   else
   {
    $('#ResetSubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    return false;   
   }
  }
  });
 }
 else
 {
  $( '#confirmUsername' ).html("");

  return false;
 }
}
```

con esta funcion logro revisar en un evento `onkeyup()` en el input de mi formulario

`<input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailReg" id="emailReg" onkeyup="checkemail()" ?>"required>`

con el cual logro correctamente validar si existe o no el correo a ser checado, mi problema reside actualmente en este evento del codigo es que tengo problemas

```
if(response=="OK")   
   {
    $('#ResetSubmit').attr('disabled','');
    return true;    
   }
   else
   {
    $('#ResetSubmit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    return false;   
   }
```

Logro perfectamente deshabilitar mi boton submit pero si el evento es true no logro deshabilitarlo.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres que cuando el _evento es true no logro deshabilitarlo_? ¿será que cuando es true quieres volver a habilitar el botón?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `$('#ResetSubmit').removeAttr("disabled");` para eliminar el atributo `disabled` de tu input, el contrario de esta función es la de agregar el atributo:`$().attr();`

Tambien puedes usar `promp` para hacer toggle entre sus estados que sería la forma más viable cuando es true o false el response:

Activar:

```
$("#ResetSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
```

Desactivar:

```
$("#ResetSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Gracias @iuninefrendor por tu respuesta esta resolvio mi problema!